# How do I find the Workflow corresponding to a specific Fiori-App?

Tags: push-notification, workflow, abap, sap-fiori

my Company wants me to enable Push-Notifications for a Fiori-App from SAP. But I can't find anyone who knows how to do that (even the Basis Team).

As far is I know now from googling it has to do something with workflows, where I don't have any experience. I tried to search the Workflow Items in SWI1, but cant find the right one (there are 1300 to choose from). I activated the Business Workflow in SPRO. In transaction SWF_PUSH_NOTIF1 it shows the green dot. But that's all I got to work right now.

Dows anyone know how I find the right one? Or knows a help article on that or have a summary of Transactions, that you need when working with Workflows? I'm completely lost right now.

If it helps, currently it's this app: [Simulating Modeling and Forecasting](https://help.sap.com/docs/CARAB/e95c8443f589486bbfec99331049704a/593a912124e1474e904b8b21309acb32.html?locale=en-US).

But in the future I need it for others too.

Comment: You must know the SQL trace and the SAP Business Workflow tables (names starting with SW). Do anything one one work item, see which tables are accessed and you should obtain the number of the work item, and SWI1 will give you a lot of information.